# passing variable in the middle on the regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

i am writing python code to match a line against a set of lines, using regex.
i want to pass variable to my regex.

Below is the regex pattern that i have come up with where i am substituting my variable in the position where i need it to match
But it is failing to match. however when i use the string directly in place of variable the regex is working fine.

```
vm_name = my_vm-84
pattern = r'(vm\.cpu\.num_cores{.+name=)%s(.+}) (\d+)' %vm_name

res = re.search(pattern, metric_data)
```

Here metric_data is string of lines as below :

```
vm.cpu.num_cores{cluster="Cluster",cluster_status="active",id="44242543-0000-4481-b494-164fd257d190",name="my_vm-84",unit="cores",workspace_id="0f2a0e8751554e92abcb35b82f2415b2"} 1
vm.cpu.num_cores{cluster="Cluster",cluster_status="active",id="50084393-8b48-ac4d-013c-2c29a114565a",name="VM-Do-not-Delete",unit="cores",workspace_id=""} 2
vm.cpu.num_cores{cluster="Cluster",cluster_status="active",id="5008842e-a4dd-1167-fc78-c3b2ec467f66",name="windows clone",unit="cores",workspace_id=""} 8
vm.cpu.num_cores{cluster="Cluster",cluster_status="active",id="5008b125-dddf-d3b0-e2c3-13a64e32511a",name="Ubuntu_new",unit="cores",workspace_id="0f2a0e8751554e92abcb35b82f2415b2"} 1
vm.cpu.num_cores{cluster="Cluster",cluster_status="active",id="9818eaf3-382f-4a64-ac7a-89cbc5c36262",name="Ubuntu-cloud-init",unit="cores",workspace_id="0f2a0e8751554e92abcb35b82f2415b2"} 1
```

any help in building my regex is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
vm_name = 'my_vm-84'
pattern = r'vm\.cpu\.num_cores{.+name="%s".+} (\d+)' %vm_name
res = re.search(pattern, metric_data)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6FbGTi/1)

Note that your sample data has double quotes around your variable value `"my_vm-84"`

Answer (score 2):

Just change your variable like this:

```
vm_name = '"my_vm-84"'
```

Trick is in the quote characters.

Answer (score 1):

The first column of the input text is json, and you should really parse it as json; that said, you are missing the double quotes in your regex:

```
pattern = r"(vm\.cpu\.num_cores{.+name=)\"my_vm-84\"(.+}) (\d+)"
```